# Guice dependency injection choosing one of two implementations based on configuration

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have two implementations of my service interface,

```
public interface Service {
   public ServiceResponse get();
}
```

One being a Mock implementation which returns a stubbed ServiceResponse and the other doing some real work with some unavailable downstream services.

Although both my RealService and MockService are ready I can only use the mock. And I want that instance to be injected depending on an environment variable. My question is how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Using spring, I can configure this utilizing component scanning providing the package that contains the mock -- thus my Mock implementation is injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an implementation of the Guice [`Provider`](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) interface that accesses the environment variable to determine which instance to provide.  And then make injection use this provider by using [ProviderBindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings).

Comment: Thanks Don. I injected the Injector within the Provider -- the provider get() checks the condition and return injector.getInstance(conditionMet ? Real.class : Mock.class)